# Tiny gap between ImageView and RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a little triangle indicating whether the user is in the registration or login screen, but there is a tiny gap between the triangle image and the RelativeLayout view it is under

[image]

That is as high as the triangle will go, and I am not sure how to raise it just 1 more pixel to get rid of that annoying gap. Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorLightTan"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:background="@color/colorCoral"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logintextBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:font="@font/americancaptain"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logintextBar3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="260dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:font="@font/americancaptain"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerButtonLogin"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="79dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-33dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/halfhalf" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.079"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/triangle" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/usernameLoginBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
    tools:textColor="@color/colorBackground" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordLoginBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="  Password"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameLoginBox"
    tools:textColor="@color/colorBackground" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signinButtonLogin"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorCoral"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordLoginBox" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to make the marginTop -20dp to see if that would raise it at all, but it did nothing to fix the issue

Comment: It seems your icon have padding

Comment: @Rajesh all the padding variables are set to nothing at the moment

Comment: Share your whole layout  and also `@drawable/triangle` with question

Comment: @brentB I ment to say Icon have padding while crop using photoshop, chek in photoshop or any image editor software

Comment: @Rajesh I added the entire .xml, and the `@drawable/triangle` is just a .png image of a triangle i made in photoshop (there is probably an easier way to make this but that's just what I did)

Comment: You can check gap is exist in triangle icon by adding different  background colour just to test image.

Comment: set image padding to -1 or -2 dp

Comment: @ChetanJoshi Thank you that helped me solve my problem. The image had 1 pixel of transparency at the top :)

Comment: see the color of the gap. If it is not yellowish like the background then there is an issue with the image you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorLightTan"
        tools:context=".LoginActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:background="@color/colorCoral"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/logintextBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:font="@font/americancaptain"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
                    android:textSize="26dp"
                    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/logintextBar3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="260dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:font="@font/americancaptain"
                    android:text="Register"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
                    android:textSize="26dp"
                    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/registerButtonLogin"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:text="" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/triangle" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-33dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/halfhalf" />
        </RelativeLayout>



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usernameLoginBox"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="  Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            tools:textColor="@color/colorBackground" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordLoginBox"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="  Password"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameLoginBox"
            tools:textColor="@color/colorBackground" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signinButtonLogin"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorCoral"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordLoginBox" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```